# Multiple AMQP configurations for Graylogs, RabbitMQ or ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp, graylog2

Here is what I would like to do:

I'm using RabbitMQ VHosts to break out different projects workflow, each vhosts has it's own logs exchange/queue, which Graylogs consumes from.

The problem is Graylogs can only configure one AMQP server and/or VHost.

What I'm looking for is a workaround by either:

1. Have RabbitMQ forward messages from one VHost (A) to another VHost (B)
2. Configure Graylogs for Multiple RabbitMQ VHosts
3. Configure ElasticSearch for Multiple RabbitMQ VHosts
4. other suggestions

So any of the above would be great or some insight as to solving my problem. I know I could just use the same VHost but that's another issue all in itself.

Update:

<strike>Looks like the #1 option is a no go</strike>
Looks like option #1 might be accomplished with the Shovel Plugin as @Jeremy has posted

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the latest version of Graylog allows you to run multiple Graylog servers. Would doing that and binding each one to different message queues solve your problem?

Comment: I want to use the same GL Server

Comment: But you can have multiple graylog server instances logging to the same ElasticSearch and MongoDb backends AFAIK, with the one web interface to access the log messages...

Comment: so I could run two instances of GL on the same server, pointing to two different RabbitMQ Servers/vhosts? Could you point me in the direction of that documentation?

Comment: I'm not totally sure if there are docs on doing this. I know that the 0.10.0 release of Graylog supports running multiple instances of the Graylog server and http://support.torch.sh/help/kb/graylog2-server/using-the-amqp-input details setting it up with AMQP, so by putting 2 and 2 together I suggested the answer. I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work but you could ask on the Graylog Google Group to be sure before trying it.